# Scrapy: Couldn't bind: 24: Too many open files

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, scrapy, twisted

I started to getting error:

```
2020-09-04 20:45:25 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.url.com/> (failed 2 times): Couldn't bind: 24: Too many open files.
```

I run Scrapy on Ubuntu and save results to Django database (Postgres).

I can't figure out where is the problem. I have just

```
class ProfilesSpider(BaseSpiderMixin,scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'db_profiles_spider'

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 20,
        'LOG_FILE': 'profiles_spider.log',
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 30,
        'DNS_TIMEOUT': 30,
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
        'RETRY_TIMES': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"

    }

    def start_requests(self):
        self._lock() # creates lock file 
        self.load_websites()
        self.buffer = []

        for website in self.websites:
            try:
                yield scrapy.Request(website.url, self.parse, meta={'website': website})
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def parse(self, response: Response):
       
        meta = response.meta
        website = meta['website']
        meta_tags = utils.meta_tags.extract_meta_tags(response)
        
        ....

        website.profile_scraped_at = now()
        website.save()
        profile.save()

    def error(self, failure):

        # log all failures
        meta = failure.request.meta
        website = meta['website']


        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            website.set_response_code(response.status,save=False)

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            website.set_response_code(WebSite.RESPONSE_CODE__DNS_LOOKUP_ERROR,save=False)

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            website.set_response_code(WebSite.RESPONSE_CODE__TIMEOUT,save=False)
        else:
            website.set_response_code(WebSite.RESPONSE_CODE__UNKNOWN,save=False)

        website.scraped_at = now()
        website.save()
```

This is my settings:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 60
SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.pqueues.DownloaderAwarePriorityQueue'
DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 4
# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 4
```

Do you know where is the problem?

EDIT:

I also did: `ulimit -n 1000000`

EDIT2:

I'm executing the spider using Django admin action and subprocess:

```
def runspider__profiles(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    ids = '.'.join([str(x) for x in queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)])
    cmd = ' '.join(["nohup", settings.CRAWL_SH_ABS_PATH, "db_profiles_spider",
                    "ids", ids, '&'])
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: Does this thread help?  https://groups.google.com/u/2/g/scrapy-users/c/rArexq4tI7I?pli=1

Comment: @tink Thanks, but no because I don't use scrapyD.

Comment: Is there a loop that opens files or connections that's not being closed? Is it the Scrapy service opening too many fds or some other service? https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html

Comment: I don't think so. But I'm running the spider using a long string of ids - 45.44.31.21 as a parameter and calling it from subproces.call  - check the update below.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html may help debugging